# Sorting the data returned by a database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, entity

In our project we have a requirement that when a set of records are returned by the database the records should be sorted with respect to the TITLE field in the record. The records will have to be sorted alphabetically but if the title of a record has a number in it then it should come after the records whose title only consists of alphabets.

Details:
we are using SQL Server , and c#. The data from the database comes to an Entity class whic forwards the data to other layers.

So, What will be the possible and effective solution for this requirement.

Comment: Is that all the information? Given the items *ab1*, *abc*, *abc1*, *abd*, should the resulting list be in that order, or should it be *abc*, *abd*, *ab1*, *abc1* or *abc*, *ab1*, *abc1*, *abd*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you have an object that hold data and have a property TITLE. Consider:

```
class Entity
{
   ...
   public string TITLE { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

You can store these entities in a `List<Entity>` and later, when you need, call the `Sort` method to sort.

For sorting to happen according to your requirements provide a `Comparer` when calling Sort. For more information see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s.aspx.
In `Compare(Entity x, Entity y)` you can compare both entities according to your need.

---

About comparing the `TITLE's`:
Try this Comparison method:

```
private static int StringComparer(string x, string y)
{
    if (!x.AllChar()) return 1;
    if (!y.AllChar()) return -1;

    return x.CompareTo(y) * -1;
}

public static bool AllChar(this string x)
{
    char[] chars = x.ToCharArray();
    bool allchar = chars.Any<char>((c) => !char.IsLetter(c));

    return !allchar;
}
```